# I Can't use font of two words in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Can I ask how to add a font to flutter consisting of two words, do I put _ or put a space or write the two words next to each other?

I mean like 'Arima' it's a font from one word so when I add it to `pubspec.yaml` I will write `-family: Arima` so if I have a font like 'Cormorant SC' what should I write in `pubspec.yaml` `-family: Cormorant_Sc` or `-family: CormorantSc` or what ?

Comment: Are you trying to have 2 different fonts for 2 words?

Comment: Can you please specify which font (with two words) do you want to use in your Flutter application?

Comment: @KaushikChandru I edit my post I tried to explain

Comment: @igdmitrov I edit my post I tried to explain

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
CormorantSC
```

in your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Appreciate if you check it and after that confirm my answer as valid. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both will work.. if you notice the example in pubspec file you will also see a font name with space

```dart
  #   - family: Trajan Pro 
   #     fonts: 
   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf 
   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf 
   #         weight: 700
```